# Unable to deploy Microsoft Bot

Tags: azure, botframework

I am currently running into a problem when trying to deploy via ZipDeploy and the Visual Studio Publish tool.

I have been following the tutorial on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-basic-deploy?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp in order to deploy my code, but I get no response on Microsoft Teams and a "Waiting for Bot to be ready" on the Web App Bot page.

I reverted to using a template for EchoBot to verify the problem is not just with my code, but my environment(?). I have been able to deploy this way before, but for some reason I cannot now.

Here is a picture of all the files within the folder.
[Files within the zip uploaded to Zip Deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3lXf.png)

Comment: I'm confused. You say 'zip deploy/VS Publish', but the the tutorial you link is 'ARM template/CLI' type deployment. Which are you using? That error means something went wrong with your deployment, but if you're using two different deployment styles and squishing them together like LEGOs, you're going to have to say step by step what you're doing so we can help.

Comment: I have been using Zipdeploy as my primary method for deployment. I already have the necessary app service, registration, and subscription. On step 5 of the link, I create the .deployment file and then zip up all of the files as shown in the picture. I go to ####.scm.azurewebsites.net/zipdeployui to drag and drop my zip file. It gives a "Deployment successful" message once everything is done on zipdeploy. I've used this method before, numerous times and it's worked so I'm not sure what my problem is now since this is a new project. @JJ_Wailes

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the deployment steps and the error you are getting under the Channels tab for Teams and Web Chat? The "Waiting for Bot to be ready" might be due to a wrong endpoint. Can you check your messaging endpoint in the bot settings? Also, one more option would be to check the 'Remove additional files at destination' in Publish settings and then republish your bot.